(Re)Use Restcontroller/RequestMapping to authorize Http requests
I would like to authorize http request or not, using a RestController class.
So far I only know the matchers like AntPathMatcher, but they are all based on string-based patterns.
I would like to reuse the already existing RequestMappings.
E.g instead of
 HttpSecurity http
 http.authorizeHttpRequests(
               authorizeHttpRequests -> authorizeHttpRequests.requestMatchers( "/api/public/my-path" ).permitAll() );

This would be nice
 HttpSecurity http
 http.authorizeHttpRequests(
               authorizeHttpRequests -> authorizeHttpRequests.requestMatchers( MyPublicRestController.class ).permitAll() );

For the acutator project here is something available, what is really nice
 final AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizedUrl authorizedUrl = auth.requestMatchers(
             EndpointRequest.to( InfoEndpoint.class, HealthEndpoint.class ) )
       .permitAll()

Is this possible?

just add @RequestMapping("foo") over your controller class and then use requestMatchers( "/foo/**" ).permitAll() - will do the same thing

Have a look inside the implementation of EndpointRequest.to(...)

@J Asgarov no thats not true, because if you have more controller with sub path, this will not work. Also if a path is not existing you get a 404 instead of 401
@Zorglube yes but this looks related to the actuator endpoint see java doc somments

It was just a guess, I though that EndpointRequest.to(...) dose some introspection on the object to extract the path.
